# If I need middleware constructor of backend controller?

Tags: laravel

In Laravel 6 I have defined routes :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api', 'prefix' => 'adminarea', 'as' => 'adminarea.'], function ($router) {

    Route::resource('ads', 'Admin\AdController');
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'ads'], function ($router) {
        Route::resource('/{ad_id}/categories', 'Admin\AdCategoriesController');
    });
    ...
```

and constructor of app/Http/Controllers/Admin/AdCategoriesController.php has line :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Auth;
...

class AdCategoriesController extends Controller
{
    private $requestData;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => []]);
        $request           = request();
        $this->requestData = $request->all();
    }
```

I wonder if really need middleware in above constructor ?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are going to use middleware in the class, then it will affect other functions defined in that particular class as well. If you define the middleware in the grouping then routes that belong to a particular group are the only one which will be affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Middleware** in **Routes** or **Controller** .

You can add Middleware to only one route group or more. like this :

```
Route::group([], function ($router) {
    $router->group(['middleware' => ['throttle'] ,'namespace' => '\Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers'], function ($router) {
        $router->post('login', [
            'as' => 'auth.login',
            'uses' => 'AccessTokenController@issueToken',
        ]);
    });

    $router->post('register', [
        'as' => 'auth.register',
        'uses' => 'AuthController@register',
    ]);
});
```

Another syntax :

```
Route::group([], function ($router) {
        $router->group(['namespace' => '\Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers'], function ($router) {
            $router->post('login', [
                'as' => 'auth.login',
                'middleware' => ['throttle'] ,
                'uses' => 'AccessTokenController@issueToken',
            ]);
        });

        $router->post('register', [
            'as' => 'auth.register',
            'uses' => 'AuthController@register',
        ]);
    });
```

Another syntax :

```
Route::get('/url','YourController@yourMethod')->middleware('yourMiddleware');
```

Or you can use **__construct** in your **Controller**.

But you don't need to use Middleware in Routes and Controller together.

[This document](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware) can help you.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, `Middleware` can be assigned to both `Route`s and `Controller`s

- When assigned to a `Route` it will affect only that `Route`
- When assigned to a a `Route::group`, it will affect all `Route`s in that group
- When assigned to a `Controller` constructor function, it will affect all methods (and their corrisponding `Route`s) in the `Controller`
- When assigned to a `Controller` method, it will affect that method (and the corrisponding `Route`s)